# How to add an auto refresh to a wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, refresh

There is a shoutbox plugin located here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/myshouts-shoutbox/

The plugin is written in PHP. Ive done everything and have been googling for days. Im really thick when it comes to PHP and Jquery etc.

Ive tried using a div refresh, but nothing changes (I seen the text fade as per the code)... it doesnt grab the new content that someone has posted. I dont know if someone can look inside that coding of the plugin and help me out?

I know it seems like I havent read through much, but I assure you I have scoured the internet (including here!) for answers and ways of doing this.

I am so lost.

Comment: Hi and welcome to our little corner of the internet. We're not here to do your homework. If you need help try to be more specific and post the code here so it can help other later.

Comment: Ive tried adding the widget to a sidebar and creating a div with the sidebar in it and auto-refreshing the entire sidebar and that still doesnt produce new results via this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is written in PHP but the loading and other stuff is handled with AJAX. There's a shout.js file and you can find the following line:

```
setTimeout(function(){ myshouts_check_stream(); },5000);
```

I think that's what you need :)